# Using GTM v5 TAGCustomFunction in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-tag-manager

I'm integrating GTM v5 (GTM + Firebase) in a Swift project, and I want to be able to call some methods when tags are triggered. However, it doesn't seem to work with Swift, although similar implementations in Objective C and Android projects did work.

Here's the class conforming to the `TAGCustomFunction` protocol :

```
import Foundation
import GoogleTagManager

final class Tags: NSObject, TAGCustomFunction {

    func execute(withParameters parameters: [AnyHashable : Any]!) -> NSObject! {
        print("YEAH ! IT WORKS !")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Everything is working well, even though I see these kind of logs:

> GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: applicationStart with parameters: (null)

But the log I'm printing is not showing…

I'm sure about the configuration of the container since this one is correctly loaded, and I use the exact same container for my Objective C project, in which it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732965/how-is-etag-used-on-youtube-api-swift), I suddenly remembered that a Swift project could embed some objective C classes.
The solution to my problem was ridiculously easy to set up once I realized that, eventhough I've never had to do it before.

I created a new **Cocoa Touch Class** like the following :

- Here is the .m :

  ```
  #import "MyCustomTagClass.h"
  #import "MySwiftClass-Swift.h"

  @implementation MyCustomTagClass

  - (NSObject*)executeWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters {
      [MySwiftClass myMethod];
  }

  @end
  ```
- And here is the .h :

  ```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import <GoogleTagManager/TAGCustomFunction.h>

   @interface MyCustomTagClass : NSObject <TAGCustomFunction>

   - (NSObject*)executeWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters;

   @end
  ```

Note that I import a header for my Swift class, which is automatically generated by Xcode. Just add *-Swift.h* after the name of your class to import it, just as I did in the .m example above.
Last, but not least, update your Swift class with **@objc** annotations at class and method declaration lines :

```
import Foundation

@objc class MySwiftClass: NSObject {

   //...

   @objc static func myMethod() {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

I hope this helped !

Answer (score 5):

I think `TAGCustomFunction` needs to have class/method `@objc` annotations, *and* the class-level `@objc` annotation needs to specify the class name, i.e.

```swift
import Foundation
import GoogleTagManager

@objc(Tags)
final class Tags: NSObject, TAGCustomFunction {

    @objc func execute(withParameters parameters: [AnyHashable : Any]!) -> NSObject! {
        print("YEAH ! IT WORKS !")
        return nil
    }
}
```